# navigation bar disappear faster than the view when use popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: ios, navigationbar, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a root vc embed in the navigation vc, I set the navigation bar hidden using
 `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`
It works fine, the navigation bar disappears.

And push the 2nd vc use
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`
In the 2nd vc set the navigation bar display. Everything goes well.

So when I clicked the 'back button' on the navigation bar, I found the navigation bar disappeared faster than the view, especially set the view's background to black, I can see 
the whole view is black just like there're not any navigation bar ever.
**I don't want this, I just hope the navigation bar will always present until the viewDidDisappear.**

[Here is a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRjmW.gif)

I use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and must fill the Animated is YES can reproduce this appearance.

For the sort,

1. Two vc in the navigation vc.
2. Root vc's navigation bar was hidden,the 2nd VC pushed from the root vc.
3. The 2nd vc made the navigation bar display.
4. Use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` to back.

Where is the code location:
ps:whatever how you set the navigation bar's hidden-property, in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear or other place, they are all the same appearance.

in the root vc's viewDidLoad
 `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`

and root vc's didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];`

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];   Where are you using this line in your code? viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear?

Comment: @jai just in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Set your first view controller as your navigationcontroller delegate and Implement these delegate methods in your first view controller.        - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated     and      - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: DO it in viewWillAppear

Comment: You can find the that the returned viewcontroller is first one and second one so can change hide/visible your navigationbar...

Comment: @KumarKl nothing changed

Comment: You only `setNavigationBarHidden:YES` in root vc's `viewDidLoad`? How could the nav bar be hidden again when nav back from 2nd vc to root vc?

Comment: @an0 yes, I put the setNavigationBarHidden:YES in root vc's viewDidLoad only.
Pay Attention:
- the navigationBar default in the hierarchy is always hidden.
- in the 2nd vc, create one new navigationBar for present, and this navigationBar don't need to handle anymore.

Comment: @sunydea I suggest you show us your vc hierarchy and highlight the problematic vc transition in a simple ascii digraph. Currently I don't quite get it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience @an0.I just edited the question again, hope you can get it.

Comment: @sunydea you didn't make it clear. Tell us exactly where do you call `setNavigationBarHidden:`.

Comment: Good @an0, I call `setNavigationBarHidden:Yes` in the root vc's `ViewDidLoad`, and call `setNavigationBarHidden:Yes` in the 2nd vc's `ViewWillDisappear`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where is Wrong

- The RootView and SubView are in the same NavigationController hierarchy.This means the navigationBar neither belong to the RootView nor to the SubView.
- The navigationBar is global and unique in this situation . You can't deal with the two view's display only using one navigationBar.

### How to solve

- In the SubView, I make a new navigationBar to replace the exiting one, and add it to the SubView's subview. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the call of `setNavigationBarHidden:Yes` from 2nd vc's `viewWillDisappear:` to root vc's `viewDidAppear:`.

I know visually this is not pleasant. I just gave you what you said you wanted: "I just hope the navigation bar will always present until the viewDidDisappear." For a nice transition you need to use custom transition.

Comment: Thanks. I get your thought and tried this way yet. This is not a perfect method. Because the root vc is not have one navigation bar, when the 2nd vc popped out the navigation hierarchy, the navigation bar is always present until the root view run over the `ViewDidAppear`, it's not a good user interface, **[see this picture](http://t.cn/8F4XnHY)**

Comment: @sunydea I just gave you what you said you wanted: "I just hope the navigation bar will always present until the viewDidDisappear." See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Frome ViewDidLoad, move [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; in ViewDidAppear method. It will work.

Comment: yes, this can solved the half part of the problem, because when back to the RootView, the NavigationBar is present for a moment and disappear later, it's not final method.

Comment: OK please once try to hide navigation bar both in ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear. (Not in ViewWillAppear)..

Comment: Nothing changed. But thanks again, when I'm trying to solve it  follow your tips,  suddenly I have an inspiration to solve this problem finally. I will make detailed description in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];` to your subVC's `viewWillAppear:` and move `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` to your RootView's `viewWillAppear:`